# Merging sublists

Tags: python, list, merge

I have this list:

```
newlis = [[6], [3], [4], [10], [9], [1], [2], [5], [7], [0], [8]]
```

I want to merge every two consecutive sublists (whether they are odd or even). I tried this code:

```
    while len(newlis) != 1:
        lis1=[(a + b) for a, b in zip(newlis[::2], newlis[1::2])]
        newlis=lis1
        print newlis
```

The result was: `[[6, 3], [4, 10], [9, 1], [2, 5], [7, 0]]`

How can I modify the code that it will print `[[6, 3], [4, 10], [9, 1], [2, 5], [7, 0], [8]]` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (`itertools.zip_longest` in python 3) :

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> [(a + b) if b else a for a, b in izip_longest(newlis[::2], newlis[1::2])]
[[6, 3], [4, 10], [9, 1], [2, 5], [7, 0], [8]]
```

This function also accept a `fillvalue` that you can use to fill the missed values with a costume value :

```
>>> [(a + b) for a, b in izip_longest(newlis[::2], newlis[1::2],fillvalue=['**'])]
[[6, 3], [4, 10], [9, 1], [2, 5], [7, 0], [8, '**']]
```

One another choice is using `chain` and `islice` :

```
>>> from itertools import islice,chain
>>> [list(chain.from_iterable(islice(newlis,i,i+2))) for i in range(0,len(newlis),2)]
[[6, 3], [4, 10], [9, 1], [2, 5], [7, 0], [8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> [[w for _, q in k for w in q] for _, k in itertools.groupby(enumerate(newlis), lambda (a,b):a//2)]
[[6, 3], [4, 10], [9, 1], [2, 5], [7, 0], [8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to import any library, you can use this simple one liner:

```
result = [sum(newlis[i:i+2], []) for i in range(0, len(newlis), 2)]
```